# Cocos2D Crash on -(id) init

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 1 Scene which contains two layers. One named BackgroundLayer and the other named GameplayLayer. Background layer looks like this:

```
-(id) init{
self = [super init];
if(self != nil){
    CCSprite * backgroundImage;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"backgroundr.png"];

    }
    else{
        backgroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
    }

    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [backgroundImage setPosition:CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2)];
    [self addChild:backgroundImage];

}
return self;}
```

That works fine. But the thing is, the GameplayLayer causes the game to crash.
GameplayLayer looks like this:

```
-(id) init{
    self = [self init];
   if( self != nil){

        }

    return self;
}
```

Also game scene looks like this:

```
-(id) init{
self = [super init];
if(self != nil){
    BackgroundLayer * backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
    [self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];

    GameplayLayer * gameplayLayer = [GameplayLayer node];
    [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:5];

}
return self;
```

}

I really dont see an issue here. But if I remove the -(id) init it wont crash. 
 Any ideas?

 Here are the last few lines of the logs:

```
    2013-03-12 00:41:41.371 CocoTest[3574:c07] cocos2d: **** WARNING **** CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE is disabled. To improve performance, enable it by editing ccConfig.h

2013-03-12 00:41:41.371 CocoTest[3574:c07] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0
2013-03-12 00:41:41.371 CocoTest[3574:c07] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self = [self init];`  in `GameplayLayer` will recurse forever. should be `self = [super init];`

Comment: There are scenarios where you need to use a `[self init]`, but they are few and far between. I wish that Xcode gave more warnings about recursive functions like that.